# Javascript conflicting on Rails 4.2.0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, owl-carousel

I'm building a Rails 4.2.0 application using two main JavaScript features. FullCalendar and Owl Carousel.

All of the assets are in the right place and when I precompile assets it makes no difference.

Is there any reason why this would be?

Could the JavaScript be conflicting somewhere?

As a note the two features are being used on different pages.

Comment: You haven't explained your problem. What do you mean 'it makes no difference'?

Comment: With things such as CSS when I run `rake assets:precompile` it used to break the styling. So originally I thought the conflict would have something to do with that. But It doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your JavaScript requirements to `application.js`:

```
//= require full-calendar.js
//= require owl-carousel.js
```

Then add `application.js` to your asset precompilation configuration located under `/config/initializers/assets`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(application.js)
```

Comment: So I've added:
`//= require viewable_fullcalendar.js
//= require viewable_calendar-editable.js
//= require owl.carousel.min.js
`
And now the carousel works which is fantastic. Could this just be a problem with FullCal?

Comment: Do you get any details about the error in the JavaScript console?  Is there a 404 error on the calendar scripts?  Or is there an error within the script?

Comment: No details. There could be an error in the script but I'm not sure what. The elements on the page are spaced out (a button at the top and bottom). If I remove the code they go next to each other. So it's like it won't render.

Comment: In a piece of code for the calendar I had:
`$(document).ready(function() {
 calendar();
});
$(document).on('page:load', function() {
 calendar();
});`

Commenting this out fixed the issue. It seemed to be blocking(?) The carousel!